# Login failed for user 'sav'. ClientConnectionId:8bb171a7-21ef-4e8b-9b25-33bab4beb828

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Sav is my user for my msSql server.

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")


public class Controller

 {
@Autowired
private ProductRepo productrepo;
@GetMapping("/")  

public List\<Product\> getAllProduct()
{
 List\<Product\> v = productrepo.findAll(); 
 return v;  }
@RequestMapping("/1")
public String welcome() {
 return "login";
}

//Creating employee rest api

//    @PostMapping("/Product")
 public Product createProduct(@RequestBody Product product)  
   return productrepo.save(product);    }

  }
```

My model

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name= "Product")
    public class Product {  
     @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

   private String id;
   @Column(name= "name")
   private String name;
  @Column(name= "description")
 private String description;

 public Product(String id, String name, String description) {
   this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.description = description;
  }

public Product() {
                                                 }

 public String getId() {
   return id;
 }

 public void setId(String id) {
   this.id = id;
 }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

    public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
}

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

  public void setDescription(String description) {
   this.description = description;
  }
```

}

And my main class

```
  `@ComponentScan("com.example.student.student.Controller.")
   @EnableAdminServer
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.student.student.productRepo")
   @SpringBootApplication()

  public class AStudentApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AStudentApplication.class, args);
}

 }`
```

My application properties

```
 spring.datasource.url= jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=product12;trustServerCertificate=true;
 spring.datasource.username=sav
 spring.datasource.password=12345
  #spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
 spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
 server.port=9003
 server.error.include-exception=true
server.error.include-stacktrace=always
```

new Error log

```
Description:

Field entityManager in com.example.student.student.AStudentApplication 
required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' that could not 
be found.

 The injection point has the following annotations:
 -@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


  Action:

   Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' in 
   your configuration.


   Process finished with exit code 1
```

I keep on getting different error with these code. I have tried different approach as well but somehow some other error occurs. I thought MSSql could also be the one of the reason but I have re-installed that still doesn't works out

Comment: Hello, please be more precise about what are the current settings, what log are you getting on the startup, what are you doing to get an error and what is the error log including stacktrace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. It's hard to tell what kind of problem you're facing if you don't share the error log

Comment: I tried running this simple Springboot program but i'm getting run time error every time it is different suppose I got one error and somehow i got solution for that in internet but after pasting that code i starts to get some other error.

Comment: Description:

Field entityManager in com.example.student.student.AStudentApplication required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1


This is the error i'm getting for now. I have searched on google and tried every solution looks like none of them are working